# Color background of label with for attribute only when checkbox is checked CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, checked, label-for

There are a lot of examples of coloring All labels when a check box is checked. I need to color just a single label with a "for" attribute

I am trying:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label[for=Sign_me_up_for_the_newsletter_and_periodic_alerts] {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <label for="Sign_me_up_for_the_newsletter_and_periodic_alerts">Sign me up for the newsletter and periodic alerts</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter_optin" id="newsletter_optin" value="yes" class="newsletter_optin">
  <br>
  <label class="text-danger" for="I_Agree_to_the_Terms_of_Agreement">I agree to the terms of agreement</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms_of_agreement" id="terms_of_agreement" value="yes" class="accept_tos">
</div>
```

When I check the checkbox, nothing happens

Comment: In CSS, `~` is the [Subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator), which matches all instances of the second element that follow the first element (not necessarily immediately) and share the same parent element. You'd need to move your labels to after your inputs for it to work. Or try [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) instead

Comment: Ah, thanks fox clarification on `~` . I am tring `input[type="checkbox"]:checked:hasl(abel[for=Sign_me_up_for_the_newsletter_and_periodic_alerts]) {
    background: green !important;
}`  Is this the proper way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with CSS [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector.

Note, I edited your markup a little, so values of a pair of `for=` and `id=` are matched.

```css
label:has(+ input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <label for="newsletter_optin">Sign me up for the newsletter and periodic alerts</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter_optin" id="newsletter_optin" value="yes" class="newsletter_optin">
  <br>
  <label class="text-danger" for="terms_of_agreement">I agree to the terms of agreement</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms_of_agreement" id="terms_of_agreement" value="yes" class="accept_tos">
</div>
```

Comment: Just a to note. I can target just the label I want with `label:has(+ input[id="myID"]:checked) {
  color: green;`
}

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution is to use JavaScript to add a class to the label when the checkbox is checked. Here's how you can do it:**

```
<style>
  /* Define the style for the highlighted label */
  .highlight-label {
    color: green !important;
  }
</style>

<div class="pull-right">
  <!-- Use a unique ID for the label -->
  <label for="newsletter_optin" id="newsletter_label">Sign me up for the newsletter and periodic alerts</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter_optin" id="newsletter_optin" value="yes" class="newsletter_optin">
  <br>
  <label class="text-danger" for="I_Agree_to_the_Terms_of_Agreement">I agree to the terms of agreement</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms_of_agreement" id="terms_of_agreement" value="yes" class="accept_tos">
</div>

<script>
  // Get the checkbox and label elements
  const checkbox = document.getElementById('newsletter_optin');
  const label = document.getElementById('newsletter_label');

  // Add event listener to the checkbox
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // If checkbox is checked, add the 'highlight-label' class to the label; otherwise, remove the class
    if (this.checked) {
      label.classList.add('highlight-label');
    } else {
      label.classList.remove('highlight-label');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Alas, I have no way to add Javascript to the application, only CSS